# Can circular saws be used in a wet application to cut concrete with a diamond blade?

Tags: safety, tools, powertools

I've seen videos of people cutting concrete using a circular saw and diamond blade, and using a hose *on the running blade* to minimize the dust.  My initial reaction is **how are they safely running water on a device that's plugged into an electrical outlet?**  The saws don't seem to be specifically designed for wet use.  Are all corded circular saws able to be used in a wet application like this?  Are the electrical motor components sealed and isolated from the blade or does it depend on the saw?  I'd like to save money and not have to buy or rent a specialty concrete saw if possible.

I have a Porter Cable PC13CSL.

Comment: If you can keep the water just on the blade maybe okay, once water gets on the motor, that can be a problem.  Would want a GFCI on the circuit and be prepare to buy a new saw.  Rent a wet use saw if wanting to use water.

Comment: As @ Echnerwal has said in his answer- dry cutting diamond blades on a circular saw can do a whole lot of cutting in concrete. It is tough on the saw. You did not mention how much you are cutting or how deep but worth a try for the cost of a decent diamond blade.

Comment: THere are comments about GFCI's to keep this from being a problem, but let me re-iterate.  YOU SHOULD 100% ALWAYS USE A GFCI ON CORDED POWER TOOLS.

Answer (score 2):

Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter, and you're there.

Or you can rent a special wet saw if you like, or buy it if you are crazy or a professional with jobs enough to justify it.

But the GFCI and not being stupid with the hose will do what's needed. Being stupid with the hose will interrupt the job and trip the GFCI. If you are using a GFCI...

Or use a dry diamond blade and a shop vacuum to catch the dust. You should still plug into a GFCI, though. Concrete is a great ground path. Dust control is vital, since it will kill your bearings and brushes if it goes into the motor air intake.

I believe you'll find that you can see sparks when running and copper bits when not running if you look in the end of your saw, so no, not sealed. I forget the model number, but my PC burnt the arbor without even using it on concrete. If abusing a saw on concrete rather than renting one made for that, get the job done within 30 days of buying it cheap from Harbor Freight, or buy a better brand for way less money at a Habitat re-store, slightly used.

Comment: So abuse the new equipment then return it under guarantee... Stunning advice and people wonder why things get expensive.

Comment: Not what I said. Use it, and get the job done. If it survives the full length of the stunning warranty, keep it around for the next (awful) job.

Answer (score 0):

Instal GFCI for your protection.

Apply grease to the rubber seal on the shaft and replenish frequently.

Important is keep it very wet, to keep the slurry away (washing away).

Recommend not to run in dry mode, it will kill the blade faster.

Be ready for damage to the bearings after some use, it happened to me, but luckily after the job was done.